Neovim command mode keymap without executing
In my vimrc I had a mapping to read the word under the cursor (<C-R><C-W>) and put it on the command line as an argument ready to search with the GrepperRg tool:
nnoremap <leader>gg :GrepperRg <C-R><C-W>
Because the argument would often need modification, a feature of the mapping was being able to modify the argument - adding or removing characters. I.e there is no <CR> at the end.
In Neovim in lua mappings look like this
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gg", "<cmd>GrepperRg <C-R><C-W>")
But using the mapping like this, outputs the error
E1255: <Cmd> mapping must end with <CR>
With Neovim, is there a way to have a shortcut which puts a string, in part from a register, on to the command line without executing it?

I would do:
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gg", ":GrepperRg <C-R><C-W>")

In both Vim and Neovim the <cmd> modifier requires that you end the mapping with <cr>.
